# How to know which Stack Exchange site to use?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask which Stack Exchange site to use? It seems to be very nuanced and my questions are routinely closed.

I just asked a C# algorithm question over at Stack Overflow, but they got angry and closed it because it wasn't Stack Overflowy enough I guess.

I've used Stack Overflow for almost a decade. I have more than 3000 reputation points. But apparently I don't know how to ask questions any more.

Anyway, until I can figure out what Stack Exchange site to go to, I just don't want to ask any questions. It just wastes my time. Frankly, I shouldn't have to read a manual in order to ask a question on the internet. I just should not.

Comment: Generally, if you aren't sure, Meta is the place to ask. You want to make sure, however, that you include enough information to make it clear what the scope of your question is. If you already know _exactly_ what you want to ask and how, put that in a quote in your question. (Concerning your Stack Overflow question, opinion based questions don't fit anywhere on the network, really. I'm not 100% on whether it's opinion based or not, but it looks _somewhat_ that way to me.)

Comment: @Kendra How is a question asking for terminology "opinion based"? Either there's a term for it or there is not. If there is not, then that is the answer. I understand that there might be more than one term for an algorithm but certainly there's not an infinite collection of terms?

Comment: @Catija As I said, I'm not 100% sold on Opinion Based, but I can see a hint of it. If it's an algorithm that does not have a set name, or that people used a variety of names for, I could see that fitting better. You can already see on the answer to that post that there's at least a little disagreement about what algorithm it is- Not really great justification for the closure, but could be what someone used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry that you feel that way but I'm not sure why you feel that your questions should always be accepted wherever they're posted. If you refuse to read the help information, you should expect to get the occasional question closed or answer deleted.

You are generally welcome to ask a meta question on the site your question was closed on to request a better explanation of why your question was closed. They may even be able to recommend a better site to ask it on. Please make an effort to ask these questions in a positive manner. Rants that only complain about why a question was closed without looking for real help will often get downvoted and closed.

Alternatively, if you think your question was on topic and the comments or the close reason explain why it was closed, read the comments and address those issues by *editing* your question. Once edited, if it addresses the issues, it may get reopened.

With regards to your final question - where do you ask which site to ask a question on - the answer to that is **here**. Meta Stack Exchange is exactly the place to ask. Note the [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) tag that I've added to your question.